# Contar palavras em Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço pra contar a quantidade de palavras que apareceram dentro de um array.
Exemplo:

```
['thiago','carlos','pereira','thiago']
```

"thiago" apareceu 2 vezes, "carlos" 1 e "pereira" 1.

Quero uma lógica que faça isso de forma dinâmica independente dos nomes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já precisei de algo parecido; essa não é a forma mais fácil de entender mas foi a mais *"bonita"* que já usei (encontrada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19395302/4551469) do SO):

```
var totais = {};
array_palavras.forEach(function(x) { totais[x] = (totais[x] || 0) + 1; });
```

Comment: Obrigado deu certo !!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Outra solução possível seria utilizando [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Não é tão compacta como uma linha, mas acaba por ficar também simples e até parecida:

```js
let nomes = ['thiago','carlos','pereira','thiago'];

const totais = nomes.reduce((acumulador, elemento) => {
    acumulador[elemento] = (acumulador[elemento] || 0) + 1;
    return acumulador;
}, {});

console.log(totais);
```

De notar que o objeto utilizado para a acumulação dos totais é o `{}` passado como segundo parâmetro do `reduce`, o que faz com que esta solução não precise de ter um objeto vazio criado anteriormente.